# submaximality and extremelly disconnectivity of Cantor Space

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{0,1\}$ be the discrete space. Then $\mathbb{N}$ many copies of $\{0,1\}$ is called Cantor space which is $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}=\mathcal{C}$.

Definition: A topological space $X$ is said to be submaximal if every dense subset of $X$ is open.
Definition: A topological space $X$ is said to be extremelly disconnected if the closure of every open set is open.

I thought of that $\mathcal{C}$ is an extremelly disconnected space since, if $U$ is an open subset of $\mathcal{C}$, it is of the form $U=\prod_{i=1}^{m} U_{i}\times \prod_{i>m} X_{i}$ where $U_{i}$ is the basic open subset of $\{0,1\}$  for each $1<i<m$ and $X_{i}=\{0,1\}$ for $i>m$. Then $\overline{U}=\overline{\prod_{i=1}^{m} U_{i}\times \prod_{i>m} X_{i}}=\prod_{i=1}^{m} \overline{U_{i}}\times \prod_{i>m} \overline{X_{i}}$  holds. Since $\overline{U_{i}}$ and $\overline{X_{i}}$ is open  for each $U_{i}$ and $X_{i}$ then $\overline{U}$ is open which completes the proof.

Is my approach is true?

On the other hand, Is the Cantor space $\mathcal{C}$ is submaximal? Is every dense subset of $\mathcal{C}$ is open? It is not difficult to see that $\{0,1\}$ with discrete topology is submaximal, but the product is a bit challenging.

Thank you for your valuable comments and helps.

Comment: You can take the subset $E$ formed by the sequences that are zero except for only one entry that is one. Every non-empty open set contains some element of this set, since we only need choose the entry that is one to be in a position larger than the $m$ in your question that would correspond to the open set. This means that this set is dense. This set is not open, since removing a finite chunk from all sequences in $E$ and get all of $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort @user85667

Comment: For extremal disconntness it does not suffice that the space has a base, such that the closure of each element is open. This is, in fact, the case in each zero-dimensional space. But the closure of *each open* subset has to be open. The Cantor space is not extremally disconnected, since first countable, extremally disconnected spaces are discrete. Or, alternatively, non-trivial powers of non-discrete spaces are never extremally disconnected, see Engelking, General topology 6.3.21 (c).

Comment: A metric space is submaximal, if and only if the subspace of its non-isolated points is discrete. In particular, a submaximal metric space without isolated points is empty. Hence, the Cantor space is not submaximal.

Comment: Thank you so much for your illuminating answers, I understood what you meant and will check The Book Of Engelking. @Ulli